# PHP: Replace rows depending regex group values?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have this text string:

```
[000] Foo
[???] Foo
[020] Foo
[???] Foo
[045] Foo
[???] Foo
[???] Foo
[110] Foo
[???] Foo
```

I need to check the [XXX] values for every row, but it needs to be smart:

If a `???` value is between `0**` rows > replace it to `0??`.

Desired result:

```
[000] Foo
[0??] Foo
[020] Foo
[0??] Foo
[045] Foo
[???] Foo
[???] Foo
[110] Foo
[???] Foo
```

Would I need `preg_replace_callback()`?

In a further step I want to expand it to logic "between 1XX and 2XX" etc, but I may be able to adapt that from a posted solution.

Test:

```
<?php

// string
$s = '[000] Foo
[???] Foo
[020] Foo
[???] Foo
[045] Foo
[???] Foo
[???] Foo
[110] Foo
[???] Foo';

// _preg_replace magic


// output
echo 'After replacement:';
echo '<pre>' . $s . '</pre>';

echo 'Desired result:';
echo '<pre>[000] Foo
[0??] Foo
[020] Foo
[0??] Foo
[045] Foo
[???] Foo
[???] Foo
[110] Foo
[???] Foo</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: Try [`preg_replace('~^\[\?{3}(?=].*?\R\[0)~sm', '[0??', $s)`](https://regex101.com/r/eV5GRr/1)

Comment: Wow, thanks. No idea what it does tho :D

Comment: Works for 0XX but it doesn't look between rows. E.g. here https://regex101.com/r/VII7hy/1 I want to match the rows between `[100]` and `[115]`

Comment: See [`(?sm)(?:^\[0\d{2}]|\G(?!\A)).*?\R\[\K\?{3}(?=.*?\R\[0)`](https://regex101.com/r/VII7hy/2).

Comment: Big thanks, that helped me a lot!

Comment: I will post then.

Comment: If my answer worked for you please consider accepting/upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a custom boundary based on a `\G` operator:

```
(?sm)(?:^\[0\d{2}]|\G(?!\A)).*?\R\[\K\?{3}(?=.*?\R\[0)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VII7hy/2)

Change `0` in `^\[0` and `\R\[0` with the values you need.

**Details**:

- `(?sm)` - DOTALL and MULTILINE modes are on
- `(?:^\[0\d{2}]|\G(?!\A))` - match either of the 2:

  - `^\[0\d{2}]` - start of the line, `[0`, and 2 digits
  - `\G(?!\A)` - end of the previous successful match
- `.*?\R\[` - any 0+ chars as few as possible, up to the first line break, then the line break (`\R`) and a literal `[`
- `\K` - omit all the text matched so far from match buffer
- `\?{3}`  - 3 `?` symbols
- `(?=.*?\R\[0)` - and require the presence of a line break followed with `[0` after any 0+ chars, as few as possible.